# ソフトウェアに意図しない挙動を行わせる質問は許容されるのか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, 質問のクローズ

疑問の背景となっているのは以下の質問です。

- [Rubyスクリプトで変換したPDFのメタデータが認識されません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5247/ruby%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fpdf%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%8D%E8%AD%98%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)

この質問は、PDFのメタデータを書き換えることで、`ScanSnap Organizer`のOCR読み取りの制限（スキャナ付属の`ScanSnap Organizer`以外で取り込んだPDFは対象外とする）を解除することを意図したものです。

[このソフトウェアの知的財産はメーカーが保持しており、リバースエンジニアリング行為は禁止されています](http://scansnap.fujitsu.com/jp/download/OrgUp1_license.html)。どのようにして制約の解除方法を知りえたのか書かれていませんので、実際に不正行為があったかは分かりません。

しかし実質的に「有償ソフトウェアを不正に利用する方法」の質問に他ならないと感じて、クローズ票を投じました。こういう質問はどこまで許容されるのでしょう？

個人的な考えでは、商用ソフトウェアに対して、意図しない挙動を実現させる質問は、**回答者が権利侵害のリスクを背負う可能性がある**のでクローズされるべきなのでは、と考えるのですが。

Comment: 国内法律を優先すべきだということはわかっていますが、http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ をどう考えるかにもよるかもしれません。そもそもPDFのメタデータを変えることがリバースエンジニアリングになるのかどうかも疑問があります。

Comment: PDFのメタデータを変えることがリバースエンジニアリングだとは言ってません。メタデータによって挙動が変わるという事実は、正当な方法で知り得ないと言っているだけです。また、本家SOで言えばjailbreakタグのように、それがソフトウェアのサポート外の挙動でも有益で共有したい情報というものは存在するので、どこかで線引きをした方がいいのではないか？という趣旨になります。

Comment: 議論の参考までに、そもそもリバースエンジニアリング自体の適法/違法性について、意見が分かれているようです。http://kanda-ip.jp/2013/08/18/1008 （最終的には個別事案という事になりそう…）

Answer (score 14, accepted):

当社社長のジョエル・スポルスキーの回答を引用します：

[Close questions based on moral objections?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86674/close-questions-based-on-moral-objections/86694#86694)

> Don't censor. It's not your job to enforce every rule that every tin-pot dictator, school administrator, or corrupt politician sets up. If you are actually personally horrified that students might access a website that doesn't meet the standards of their school, don't answer the question, but don't block the acquisition of knowledge just because you don't like the purpose that knowledge will be used for.
>
> In this particular case, of course, the question was off-topic because it had nothing to do with programming, so it was OK to close it as off-topic.
>
> But as a general rule, Stack Overflow exists to spread knowledge, not to give smug people the chance to play petty censorship games. The value of the diffusion of knowledge by far outweighs any interest this community might have in enforcing someone else's arbitrary rules, and we cannot possibly claim to have enough information, or the moral authority, to make decisions over whether or not a given individual has the right to even learn about how proxies work, or how to work around them.
>
> Once again: the question was off-topic, and if you are uncomfortable answering a question which you think will be used in a way you are uncomfortable with, just don't answer it. But to decide that this community has an interest in the *repression* of the transmission of engineering and scientific knowledge goes deeply against everything that Stack Overflow stands for.

当社は情報を広げたい派です。

他社のルールに違反しているかどうかを判断するのは当コミュニティの役割ではないです。何かの理由で回答するのが心配な場合、回答しなくてもよいです。そして、自分が同意した利用規約に違反するのはいけませんが、違反せず情報の共有ができるのであれば、あとは個人の判断になります。

自分が提供した知識にどのような使い道を見出だすかは読む人の判断にもよりますし、あなた自身が違反をしない限り**共有することを基本**にしてほしいと思っています。

Comment: 同じ質問への別の回答にある「SO上では情報をやり取りしているだけで、実際に実行しているわけではない（And we're not even doing it, we're just talking about it.）」に納得しました。が、[こちらのmeta.seの質問](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142864/157841)への回答では「他者のソフトウェアをクラッキングするのを助けてほしいという質問はStack Exchangeの利用規約に反します（Questions that ask for help with cracking someone else's software are in violation of Stack Exchange's TOS anyway.）」とされています。違反行為であるかを明示した質問かどうかの違いと考えればよいでしょうか。

Comment: @ento TOS上では、質問を聞く権利があるかは質問者の責任です。TOSを守っているかどうかは質問者に責任あるため、聞いた質問をそのまま受け取るべきだと思います。悪用かどうかの判断をすると数多くの質問が悪用な可能性もあるし、それよりユーザーを信用したほうがいいんじゃないですか？

Comment: @3100 編集ありがとうございます！遠慮しなくても、編集をどんどんしてくれたら幸甚です！「それを言いながら」は前のたたき台で残ってしまったことなんで、あまり現在の文書に意味がないですね（もっともっとはTOSについて間に書かれたとき、「それを言いながら」は「TOSで質問者の責任です」と言いたかったです）。

Comment: TOS = Terms of Service ですかね。知らなんだ。（あまり日本語圏では馴染みがない？）

Comment: @yohjp そうですか？日本語でもっと自然な言い方ありますか？

Comment: @jmac 日本語圏のサイトでは「サービス利用規約」、または単純に「利用規約」が自然かと思います。

Comment: @jmac なるほど、検閲はコミュニティの仕事ではなく、共有を優先するという方針は納得です。ただこの質問に関して言えば、[第一版では「OCR非適用のPDFを検索可能なPDFに変換する方法」という直截的なタイトル](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5247/revisions)でした。その後コミュニティの手によって過剰編集され、現在の質問へ書き換えられました。質問者は本当にRubyスクリプトに関する情報の共有を望んでいたのか懐疑的です。

Comment: @jmac ユーザーを信用することには同意です。ただ、上でリンクしたmeta.seの回答では「クローズ・通報すべき」とあり、一見こちらの回答と矛盾しているようにみえたので質問しました。「クローズ・通報すべき」としているのは「loop-hole」のような明らかに「利用規約に違反する質問です」と言っているかのような表現がある場合だと思いますが、そういう質問についてはStack Exchangeとしては通報してもらった方がうれしいですか? それとも権利者から連絡があったものだけ対応する、というスタンスでしょうか。

Comment: @quesera2 最初の大幅な編集は、一応[質問者が承認した](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2609)ものではあります。

Comment: @jmac ニュアンスはなんとなくわかりましたが、ちょっと大幅に文章をいじっちゃいそうなのでこれ以上はやめておきます。どなたか、良い訂正が可能でしたら不自然な部分を直していただきたいです。

Comment: @ento 例えば、SOの質問にMS Windowsの社内コードが質問に入った場合、「利用規約違反です！」に見えるかもしれませんが、もし質問者がMS社の承認を得た上で投稿したかどうかをこちらで判断できません。そのため、質問者の同意した利用規約上では質問者の義務であり、質問者の責任になります。もし上記の例ではMS社から承認を取れなかったとすると、MS社が当社へ連絡し、「このコードを外しなさい」と言ったらそのプロセスもあります。結論からいうと、当コミュニティが質問者は利用規約違反をしたかどうか判断するべきではないです。僕に知らせたとしても、確認方法がなくて、何もできないから通報してもあまり効果はないと思います。（もちろん、悪用なコード等が投稿に入った場合、それを知らせてください。ユーザーが傷つけることなら、早速知らせたほうがいいですが、コードの権利、他ソフトの利用規約の違反かどうかは当コミュニティの誰にも傷を付けないので、通報しなくてもいいです）

Comment: @jmac [このmeta.seの回答](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142868/157841)は古くなっている、という理解でokですか?

Comment: @ento はい、そうです。そのクローズ理由もなくなりましたし、その人は英語版SOのモデレーターです（社員ではありません）

Comment: @jmac なるほど、理解しました。

Answer (score 2):

SOjaの方針とは別に、日本の事情をまとめておきます。日本では司法による有罪・無罪とは別に、警察の逮捕による社会的制裁の影響が大きいです。そこで警察の方針がわかる事例を紹介します。

- 2004年 [ACCS不正アクセス事件](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/topics/accs.html)
  CGIパラメーターを書き換えることで想定されていないデータにアクセスを行った。裁判の過程で、検察は当該データは認証のあるFTPでアクセスする設計であり認証のないHTTPでのアクセスは不正アクセスであるとの主張がなされた。
  これにより[サイバー・ノーガード戦法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E6%88%A6%E6%B3%95)という語も生まれた。
- 2010年 [岡崎市立中央図書館事件](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B2%A1%E5%B4%8E%E5%B8%82%E7%AB%8B%E4%B8%AD%E5%A4%AE%E5%9B%B3%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)
  システムは１リクエスト１DBセッションという、技術者から見ればあり得ない設計であった。しかし、設計の問題ではなく１秒１リクエストを行ったアクセス者に犯罪性があるとみなされ逮捕された。
- 2012年 [パソコン遠隔操作事件](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E9%81%A0%E9%9A%94%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)
  犯罪内容そのものより、杜撰な捜査により多数の誤認逮捕者を出した。
- 2019年 [アラートループ事件](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)
  アラート表示を繰り返すいたずらコードをウイルスとみなすだけでなく、ウイルス作者に対する捜査は行われることなく、当該ページを紹介するリンクを書き込んだ者だけを補導・家宅捜索・書類送検した。

判断は各自に任せますが、回答者には違法行為は行わないのはもちろんのこと、警察に逮捕されないよう慎重に行動することをお勧めします。